# image taken when in portrait mode should retain in landscape mode in android

Tags: android, orientation, android-camera, landscape-portrait

I am creating an application in which on click on the action bar item, the camera activity starts, and after capturing and saving the pic, it displays it on the main activity.

Now if i start the Camera from the MainActivity while in portrait orientation, and switch to landscape orientation in the Camera Activity,  take the picture, and click on the Save button, it returns to the MainActivity, but image is not displayed, this is I guess because the main activity is getting reloaded, but I a not sure though.

How do I have to retain the image even after the change in orientation.

MainActivity.java

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     switch (item.getItemId()) {
     case R.id.menu_camera: 

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        // file creation for saving video
        Uri fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);  
        if (fileUri != null) {
            targetFile = fileUri.getPath();

            // setting file image name
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);   

            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);

            startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
        }

        return true;
```

onActivityResult()

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
            ImageView imgPicture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPicture);
            if (targetFile != null) {
                theFile = targetFile;
                imgPicture.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(theFile));
            }

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Your picture could not be saved.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ActionBarTest.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:launchMode="singleTop">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: do you have onActivityResult() method?

Comment: I have updated the question and added onActivityResult() method. Thanks !

Comment: also the size of the actual image eats alot of memory you might consider scaling it down

Comment: "this is I guess because the main activity is getting reloaded, but I a not sure though." as for this part set a breakpoint in you onActivityResult() and debug to see whats the deal

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use this to be able to know how the image saved and then make bitmap or whatever based on that

```
public static int getExifRotation(String imgPath) 
    {
        try 
        {
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imgPath);
            String rotationAmount = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(rotationAmount)) 
            {
                int rotationParam = Integer.parseInt(rotationAmount);
                switch (rotationParam) 
                {
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                        return 0;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                        return 90;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                        return 180;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                        return 270;
                    default:
                        return 0;
                }
            } 
            else 
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

also check

```
if(bitmap.getWidth() > bitmap.getHeight()){}
```

that will let you know if the picture is landscape because width would be greater than height
and use the bitmap constructor that takes matrix to rotate:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(90); //or whatever
```